# Zend Framework 404 error issue in new controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller, http-status-code-404

I am very new to ZF and I am working on an already built application. My task is to create web service in the application. I have setup the application locally and its working fine. So I have added a new controller and could access in localhost, but when I tried to access the same in server, it results in 404 error, but other controllers can be accessed perfectly.

AllowOverride All and Apache mod_rewrite is enabled in the server. Does anybody have any idea aboout this problem. I am sitting with this error for 2 days ..

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
          DocumentRoot /path/to/site/public
          ServerName sitename.com
          ServerAlias www.sitename.com
       <Directory /path/to/site/public>
          AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Controller code:

```
class APIController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */

    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

        // Setup REST server
        $server = new Zend_Rest_Server();
    $server->setClass('APIHandlerClass');
    $server->handle();
    exit;
    }


}
```

I am accessing it with the url **site.com/API** It will show an XML in actual case.

**EDIT**:

I have setup the application in a local linux system and I found that the problem is related to the linux.

I have tried the following:

1. Created a new controller which resulted in 404.
2. Copied an existing controller and renamed the orginal controller's name. Then I have changed the code in copied controller. I accessed the my controller and it worked!
3. Copied an existing controller and renamed the copied controller. I called the copied controller with new name, which showed 404 error.

My question is do I need to specify the new controller name any where!? I didn't find any documentation regarding this and I even created view files for the controller.

Comment: We need more info. Can you give class name of the controller, its location within your project, and an example URL that you would expect to work but is giving a 404?

Comment: If other controllers work, the problem is not related to your vhost or rewrite setup. What is the filename and location of the APIController class?

Comment: Hi @TimFountain in localhost its showing the XML, but when accessing in test server it shws 404 page. Filename:APIController.php and location:/application/controllers

Comment: Okay - do the other controllers work on the test server? Do you get a ZF 404 page or an Apache one?

Comment: Yes other controllers are working file. I am getting the custom 404 error page.

Comment: Is one server running Windows/Mac OS?

Comment: In local the application is running in Windows using WAMP. Test server is linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the application works locally in Windows but doesn't work on the test server running Linux, it's likely to be a case-sensitivity issue. Check the case of folders, including the controllers folder and the views/scripts folders (both should be lower case).

Comment: Every folder names are in lower case. The thing is that all other controllers are working in test server but the newly created controller shows 404. Do we need to specify the newly added controller in any config file.

Comment: Hi Tim can you check the edited part in my question. I setup the app in linux system.

Comment: You don't need to specify the new controller anywhere if it's in `application/controllers`. It's still likely to be a case sensitivity issue, probably caused by your use of an all uppercase controller name. Can you try it with the class name as `ApiController` and the filename `ApiController.php`?

Comment: You are right! :) It was the naming issue. My controller name was APIController.php so I have changed it to ApiController.php. Also we need to ensure the permission is 755 for the newly created controller.  Thank you Tim you saved me ;)